# QListWidget working as a menu - need to be able to activate menu options using number keys rather than just getting focus

Tags: qt, accessibility, qlistwidget

This application is for accessibility so will be used by blind/visually impaired users amongst others. So it has a listWidget on the screen disguised as a menu using style sheets. The functionality behind each item on the list needs to be accessed in the following ways: – mouse click – up and down arrows to select then hit return key – number key (voice says “press 1 for email” etc) – hands free voice activation – Braille input

the last two I have not got to yet because I am failing to get the first 3 working (I can get all of them working but not all at the same time, fixing one breaks another). The listWidget already processes number keys (if you press 4 the 4th row gets selected – I need pressing 4 to run the menu item functionality without a second user input) but I am just missing something in how it works.

Is this something I just need to do with different object?

Comment: I am not sure what qt runs on, so here is some comments: Usually hands-free stuff relies on what is on the screen to work. So if your link or whatever simply says email, but you code it to run only when 1 is said/pressed, nobody would know that unless you tell them before. Re Braille input, can you expand your concerns about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For `mouse click`, I think it's straightforward to implement menu functionalities in respective `clickevents` of widgets in listwidget.
2. Use `keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *);` to process `up`, `down` and `return` keys in combination with `listwidget->hasFocus()` if needed.
3. Use the same `keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *);` to process `number` keys.

Comment: Yes, I have tried the keyPressEvent but that means I have to start coding everything in the KeyPressEvent for the other objects on the page because keyPressEvent is on the window? - unless I am missing something?  If that is the only way, I can do it that way it just seems clunky when the listView is obviously already handling numbers  automatically, I was hoping for something within the listWidget, hoping I had just missed something :-)                               Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: you have to implement it with the combination of listwidget->hasFocus() and keypressevent.

Comment: So I put if(listWidget->hasFocus()){...} in the keypressevent??

Comment: Yeah like that you can handle functionalities of different listwidgets independently

Comment: How blonde of me, should have seen that, very new to Gui, usually do the back end.  Thanks :-)